On Windows 10, how do I disable the mouse middle-click (and drag) scroll feature?
I middle click links all the time in my browser, but in Windows there is a middle-click to scroll feature where if you middle click and drag, this icon appears as the cursor:

And it starts scrolling the screen, often wildly uncontrolled... and the click on the link is completely lost.
I'd like to disable this feature if I can as I have a wheel for scrolling, and this feature has only ever interfered, not once have I wanted this behaviour.
I don't think this is hardware specific, but this is on a Lenovo T490s, with a classic Microsoft wired wheel mouse.

There are apps such as free X-Mouse Button Control that can intercept the middle mouse click, but that would also affect other middle-mouse-button behavior.

There are apps such as free X-Mouse Button Control that can intercept the middle mouse click, but that would also affect other middle-mouse-button behavior.
However, you can change the parameters for drag. This would affect drag-and-drop everywhere.

The RegEdit linked item seems like it would almost work, but I tried and it didn't work. :-( It feels like what I want is a tool/script like "AutoHotKey" that can basically do... "If current app handles middle click, great, if it doesn't, DO NOTHING" but I don't know if there's an ability to do this.

This is a Windows feature, which as far as I know cannot be easily disabled.
If your mouse has software to control button functions, that might be able to disable or change it.
I believe this can be changed with programs like, AutoHotKey.
